# Rotate boxes along an axis

Tags: c#, directx, mdx

I have 4 Boxes which are positioned like you can see in the following picture:

[image]

Now I want to turn them along the Y-Axis (left-handed, red line).

I use Managed DX an my first idea was to say for every box:

```
device.Transform.World = Matrix.RotationY(Geometry.DegreeToRadian(2)) * BoxPosition;
```

That works fine for the top and the bottom box. But the left and right box are turnling along there Y-Axis which is another one. Can someone help me how to turn them on the right Y-Axis (not the global Axis)? Position of the complete box in right-hand coordinates:

```
x = 12
y = 0
z = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the other way round:

```
device.Transform.World =   BoxPositionWithinGroup
                         * Matrix.RotationY(Geometry.DegreeToRadian(2))
                         * GroupPositionInWorld;
```

Where `GroupPositionInWorld` would be `Matrix.Translation(12, 0, 0)` and `BoxPositionWithinGroup` describes a box' local position within the group (relative to the group position).

If you want to read more about DirectX and matrices, check out [my blog post](http://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/directx-and-matrices/).

Comment: Hi, that doesnt work... When I do this, the top and the bottom box rotate along there Y-Axis and the left and the right box move to the left or right (rotate on the global Y-Axis).

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Where is the global origin?

Comment: No :-( I have this complete box (Position right-hand: x = 12, Y = 0, Z = 0). And I want to rotate the complete Box along the Y-Axis (left-hand) but not the global.

Comment: Then you'll need another transformation. See the updated answer.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I have a question to BoxPositionWithinGroup. I dont know what i write her. Currently the global position of left is x: 12, y: -4.5, z: 0 and right is y: 4.5

Comment: Isn't that the top and bottom position? If you set `GroupPositionInWorld` to `(12, 0, 0)`, the local positions will be `(0, -4.5, 0)` and `(0, 4.5, 0)`.